# RETURN REF CURSOR FROM PROCEDURE BY SELECT

Tags: oracle

i need to return ref cursor in select statement .
i'm use below code i need another type to return data .
sorry i remove a code some out put variable (the true number of column return in ref cursor it's **14** )
but need any type to return data easily to can check it working fine or not.

```
        DECLARE
           TYPE rc IS REF CURSOR;
           v_cur                      rc;                --declare ref cursor variable
           LIST_ID                    VARCHAR2 (250);
           PERSON_NO                  VARCHAR2 (250);

        BEGIN
           MOI_SERVICES.HCR_INQUIRIES_PKG.GET_SUSPECTED_LIST_PRC (148608947,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  NULL,
                                                                  v_cur,
                                                                  V_STAUS, -- 0 FAIL -- 1 SUCCESS
                                                                  V_MSG);


           LOOP
              FETCH v_cur
                  INTO LIST_ID,
                      PERSON_NO;
                EXIT WHEN v_cur%NOTFOUND;

         DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (
                    'LIST_ID = '
                 ||LIST_ID 

                END LOOP;

              CLOSE v_cur;
             END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of a REF CURSOR is that you open the cursor, but whoever called you does the fetching and the closing. Using SQL*Plus or Oracle SQL Developer, here is a simple example using anonymous PL/SQL; the "print" command does the fetching, displaying and cursor closing.

```
SQL> var rc refcursor;
SQL> begin
  2    open :rc for select * from dual;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc

D
-
X
```

Calling a function would look like this:

```
SQL> create or replace function f return sys_refcursor is
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3  begin
  4    open l_rc for select * from dual;
  5    return l_rc;
  6  end f;
  7  /

Function F compiled

SQL> exec :rc := f;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print :rc;

D
-
X
```

Best regards, Stew Ashton

Comment: thanks , the data return in v_cur variable above from my procedure i need to fetch this data and show it.not by dbms.output . 
please you can help me to how i can write a code

Comment: Your PL/SQL code runs in the database. The database cannot "show" data.Even dbms_output does not "show" data, it puts it into a buffer and the calling program retrieves the data from the buffer. You have to tell us what tool or product or program is calling the database.